# SQL syntax for a function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code, syntax somewhere is not correct,

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Greeting](@Name [varchar])
RETURNS [int] AS 
BEGIN
    Declare @Gender  varchar
    Declare @Greeting  varchar
    select @Gender =  Gender from [NameData].[dbo].[Names] where Name = @Name 
    select @Greeting = (case when @Gender = 'Female' then 'Ms.' else 'Mr.');
    RETURN @Greeting
END

GO
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Anyone can help?

Thanks

Comment: Please format your code, and give us the actual error that you're getting.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: You missed `END` in your case statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the `end` to your `case` statement.  Probably more importantly, you are not using length specifications for `varchar`.  In SQL Server *always* use length specifications.  The default value depends on the context -- and in this context, the value is 1, which will produce incorrect results.

You should also end your statements with semicolons.    And, fix the return value, because you do not seem to be returning an integer.  So:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Greeting](
    @Name varchar(255)
)
RETURNS varchar(255) AS 
BEGIN
    Declare @Gender varchar(255);
    Declare @Greeting  varchar(255);
    select @Gender = Gender from [NameData].[dbo].[Names] where Name = @Name ;
    select @Greeting = (case when @Gender = 'Female' then 'Ms.' else 'Mr.' end);
    RETURN @Greeting;
END;
```

You do realize that all unrecognized names will be given a "greeting" of "Mr.".  I assume that is intentional.  Also, the function can be simplified, but I'm following your original logic as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
RETURNS [int]
```

but are trying to return @Greeting which is declared a varchar

And also missing end for case statement.

Answer (score 2):

You missed `END` in your case statement:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Greeting] (@Name [varchar(255)])
    RETURNS [int] --also this will need to be changed to varchar() 
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Gender VARCHAR(255)   --added varchar length
        DECLARE @Greeting VARCHAR(255) --added varchar length

        SELECT @Gender = Gender
        FROM [NameData].[dbo].[Names]
        WHERE NAME = @Name

        SELECT @Greeting = (
                CASE 
                    WHEN @Gender = 'Female'
                        THEN 'Ms.'
                    ELSE 'Mr.'
                    END  --added this
                );
        RETURN @Greeting
    END
    GO
```

Comment: You also need to specify an **explicit length** for your `VARCHAR` - otherwise, you end up with **1 character** strings which is usually not what you want ....

Comment: @marc_s I agree, I updated my answer with the varchar length. Thanks!

Comment: And, that one as well. :)